# Check that the following set systems are Sigma-Algebra over $ \mathbb{R}^{N} $

Tags: general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

Check that the following set systems are $ \sigma $ algebra over $ \mathbb{R}^{N} $:

a) $ \mathcal{A}_{1}:=\left\{A \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}: A\right.$ is  most countable $ \} $

b) $ \mathcal{A}_{2}:=\left\{A \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}: A\right.$ is finite or $ \mathbb{R}^{N} \backslash A$ is finite $ \}$

c) $ \mathcal{A}_{3}:=\left\{A \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}: A\right.$ is most countable or $ \mathbb{R}^{N} \backslash A$ is most countable $ \}$

d) $ \mathcal{A}_{4}:=\left\{A \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}: A \subset B\right.$ or $ \left.\left(\mathbb{R}^{N} \backslash A\right) \subset B\right\}$ with a fixed $ B \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$.

My approach would be:

a) Since for uncountable $ ℝ^{n}$ already $ℝ^{n}$ ∉A1, $ℝ^{n}$ cannot be a σ-algebra for arbitrary sets $ℝ^{n}$≠0. (In the set of all non-empty sets are contained non-countable sets, so $ℝ^{n}$ cannot be a σ-algebra for any non-empty set.

b) Is not a σ-algebra, since the sets An={n} with n∈ℕ are finite and thus lie in $ℝ^{n}$, but it holds ∪An=ℕ and neither ℕ nor ℝ - ℕ are finite.

c) I had shown that it is a σ-algebra (proving the free conditions).

**d) I am not getting anywhere here.**

Are my thoughts on a), b) and c) correct, or is it possible to show this more nicely?  - How could one now demonstrate for d) whether it is a sigma algebra or not?

An $\sigma$ algebra over $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ is a set system $\mathcal{A} \mathcal{P}\left(\mathbb{R}^{N}\right)$ with the following properties:

- $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$
- $A \in \mathcal{A} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \mathbb{R}^{N} \backslash A \in \mathcal{A}$
- $ A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots \in \mathcal{A} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \bigcup_{i-1}^{\infty} A_{i} \in \mathcal{A} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thoughts on b) are correct.

It's not quite clear what you mean by c) but I will take your word that you have proved it.  (If you haven't, the argument is similar to the one given for d) below, breaking into two cases, where either one of the $A_i$'s is co-countable or all of the $A_i$'s are countable.)

For a) you have the right idea at the beginning, but most of the rest of the explanation doesn't make any sense and should be removed. I would not say "$\mathbb R^n$ cannot be a $\sigma$-algebra", since that is not what you are being asked, I would rather say "$\mathcal A_1$ cannot be a $\sigma$-algebra."  Also I don't have any idea what you mean by "arbitrary sets $\mathbb R^n\neq 0$", or "In the set of all non-empty sets are contained non-countable sets".

However, your first point, that $\mathbb R^n\notin \mathcal A_1$, is indeed enough to show $\mathcal A_1$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

For d), notice that if $A_i\in \mathcal A_4$ is a sequence of sets and any one of them satisfies $\mathbb R^n\backslash A_i\subseteq B$, then we have
$$\mathbb R^n \backslash \bigcup_j A_j \subseteq \mathbb R^n\backslash A_i\subseteq B,$$ and otherwise we have
$A_i\subseteq B$ for all $i$, giving us
$$\bigcup_j A_j\subseteq B,$$
so $\mathcal A_4$ is closed under countable unions.  You can easily verify it is closed under complements as well, and contains $\emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explanation to d). According to that Rn∉A1, is indeed enough to show A1 is not a σ-algebra subtask a) is also clear to me

Comment: I now have a question about showing the other two conditions. Can I say R^n is in A4, because R^n/R^n = ∅ for a fixed B?
if B is a subset of R^n then the complement is R^n/(R^n/A ...B)⊆A?
Is that right somehow??

Comment: It’s true $\mathbb R^n\in \mathcal A_4$, but you don’t have to show that directly.  You just have to show $\emptyset\in \mathcal A_4$, which is true since $\emptyset\subseteq B$.  As for the other part, the complement of $\mathbb R^n\backslash A$ is just $A$.